# How does an MS-Access SQL query run on a remotely located .mdb file?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to understand how making a query to a .mdb file works.
Suppose the file is located on a share drive, PC2, I open it programmatically from PC1.

When I make a connection to a .mdb file, I assume no "instance" of MS Access is started on the PC2 (since it's a simple file server). Is this correct?

When I make a SQL query, does it have to copy the table locally, and run the query then return my results and toss away the table and any excess data?

What happens if I "order by" on a query? is the entire query returned, then locally ordered, or somehow ordered remotely?

I'm sure I have other questions, but I'm trying to understand how connecting to an MDB file works from a remote location. (we have a decent amount of latency where I am located, so a particular query can take 9 seconds, which in my case is unacceptable, I'm trying to understand how this is working and if it can be improved).

I'm running with c# in this case, I don't expect that should make much difference, but may in your response.

Answer (score 3):

> When I make a connection to a .mdb file, I assume no "instance" of MS Access is started on the [remote machine] (since it's a simple file server). Is this correct?

Yes. The application will be interacting with a copy of the Access Database Engine on the local machine, which in turn retrieves the information from the database file on the remote machine.

> When I make a SQL query, does it have to copy the table locally, and run the query then return my results and toss away the table and any excess data?

Not necessarily. Depending on the indexing scheme of the tables(s) involved, the Access Database Engine may only need to retrieve the relevant indexes and then determine the specific pages in the data file that contain the records to be retrieved. In some cases it may need to retrieve the entire table (e.g., when a full table scan is required), but that it not always the case.

> What happens if I "order by" on a query? is the entire query returned, then locally ordered, or somehow ordered remotely?

The Access documentation says that indexes will speed up sort operations (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010341594.aspx)), suggesting that the Access Database Engine can retrieve the required rows from the remote file in sorted order.

Comment: TO go lower - it is likely that access works like every other database and organizes the file internally into pages. It iwll not load tables etc. but pages that it needs. In case of an index it can possibly avoid loading all pages that contain the table data. Note that this approach makes access likely to get corruption when multiple clients access the server at the same time with updates AND something bad happens (power failure, disconnect) and some parts are not consistent.

Comment: Will paging function via file sharing with a remote PC (distinct from a file server) as specified by the OP?

Comment: @Tim The Access Database Engine doesn't particularly care if the remote machine is a "PC" or a "file server"; it just reads and writes the files in the SMB shared folder in either case (and in cooperation with other copies of the Access Database Engine that might be working with the file at the same time).

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought that without a server handling the file processing requests, that it would need to copy the file across. But then networks/hardware are not my strong-point, so thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Access databases are accessed through Windows file page locks. My understanding was that Microsoft added this page locking for use by MS Access (but is also available for any file through the Windows API). Because the instance is local and collisions and conflicts are handled through file page locks, client-server contention is an issue. Access has known issues here. It's why one should switch to SQL Server Express (also free) whenever possible. (But, yes, MS Access has a certain level of convenience.)

Comment: Thus if you have a table with 1 million rows, and the sql selects one row, then a bit of the index + the ONE row are pulled local (this assumes the one record fits inside of a page. So a page can contain a few records, but at the end of the day the database engine thus only "reads" the one page of data from the file - the location of that file can be a USB jump drive, your local drive, or a drive on the server - Access does not know or care - it simply opening a windows file and plucking out part of the file where the record resides based on that index.

Answer (score 0):

Your instincts are correct, mdb/mde dbs are just glorified text files which must be processed locally. Here are some tips on network performance: http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm

But since SQL Server Express is free, there is almost no excuse for not migrating, especially since Access has a tool to manage that for you. In a low volume multi-user environment (2-10 for example), MS Access can work ok, but for enterprise solutions where a higher volume of users and/or transactions is in any way possible, you are dicing with disaster.

Comment: So regarding sql server, any sites you can recommend for actually using? I tried doing some searches on configuring/setting up, but those just basically show how to install and that's about it (not actual usage).

Comment: Here's as good a place to start as any, with some links at the end worth checking out before you get stuck in: 
http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/a/Migrating-To-Sql-Server-With-The-Access-Upsizing-Wizard.htm

SQL Server is very forgiving, and once you get over the visual differences, you will find it pretty straight-forward. You can even set up a DSN via a query in your access db and keep using the old builder if you prefer - here are some more great tips:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39611/main-considerations-when-moving-from-ms-access-programming-to-sql-server

Comment: Just re-read your question, maybe you meant this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to Gord's answer...

Access databases are accessed through Windows file page locks. My understanding was that Microsoft added this page locking specifically for use by MS Access (but is also available for any file through the Windows API).

Because the instance is local and collisions and conflicts are handled through file page locks, client-server contention is an issue. Access has known issues here. It's why one should switch to SQL Server Express (also free) whenever possible. But, yes, MS Access has a certain level of convenience; SSE has a bigger footprint and a far less friendly GUI

All desktop databases have client/server issues. Gord's answer matches my knowledge. The point of indices is to reduce the amount of table data that needs to be pulled locally. Pulling the index is a relatively small task in comparison to the table data. This is standard index optimisation, although I would say it is even more important for desktop databases due to the remote data and, ugh, file paging.

In general the Access (JET) engine does NOTHING remotely. It's all file data grabs and executed locally in in the local MSA/Jet engine. You know this because the engine is installed locally and doesn't have to be installed on the file host. It is, however, a convenient quick and dirty way of dispersing processing loads. :)